# "No routes matches" when using current_page in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, current-page

Has anybody experienced routes mysteriously becoming undetectable when using current_page? in Rails 3? Even with a fully generated scaffold complete with routes, a view, and a controller, I am getting a "No route matches" error.

Here's the code:

```
if current_page?(:controller => 'users', :action => "show")
```

If I add a "match" command to routes.rb, it works fine, but why would I need to do that if the resources have already been created? What am I missing?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You're missing the `id` parameter from this helper:

```
current_page?(:controller => "users", :action => "show", :id => "1")
```

It expects you to pass a full route through. If you don't want this and only want to match on the controller and action then I would recommend coding your own.

Comment: Is there any way to make it not worry about the `:id` parameter? E.g. can we use regex or something? Or is there another helper that can be used in place of `current_page?`

Answer (score 20):

If you just want to test the current controller, you can do the following:

```
if params[:controller] == 'users'
```

Similarly, if you're using a namespaced controller, you can just use a slash to separate the namespace(s) from the controller name, e.g.:

```
if params[:controller] == 'advertising/users'
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your routes, to look for a generic `show` action without ID you could look for e.g. `!current_page?(:controller => "users", :action => "index")`.